# Why change the values of 2d Array in C Language?

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

Here This my simple Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int row = 2,col = 5;

    //This my word array with new line character and ABCDE and FGHIJ
    char hello[] = "ABCDE\nFGHIJ\n";


    //Here i put these letters into 2d char array and print end print each elements
    char grid[col][row];
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<row;i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<col;){
            if(hello[count] != '\n'){
                grid[i][j] = hello[count];          
                printf("%c ",grid[i][j]);
                j++;                
            }
            count++;    
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    puts("--------------------------------");


    //Here i print each elements again
    for(int p = 0; p<row;p++){
        for(int q = 0; q<col;q++){
            printf("%c ",grid[p][q]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Finally accept this

```
ABCDE
FGHIJ
```

But result is

```
ABFGH
FGHIJ
```

What is the reason of this phenomenon. My intension is to put each letter into grid 2d char array. But after I printed each element inside it, it shows wrong.

Comment: 2D arrays in C are stored in row-major order.  Change `char grid[col][row];` to `char grid[row][col];`.

Comment: Yeah, looks like you correctly ordered row/column when addressing the matrix, but not in declaring it.  Should be as simple as fixing the declaration as jdc recommended.

Comment: It's weird that the spaces disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

You shall increase count variable in if block.